# How to get all stderr within a for loop?

Tags: bash, for-loop, stderr

I want the `stderr` of all files within a for-loop. So far only the first one in the for loop was written into `summary.txt`.

My codes:

```sh
SAMPLES="SRR1 SRR2 SRR3 SRR4"
    
 for SAMPLE in $SAMPLES; do hisat2 -p 24 -x /home/genome_g7b -1   /home/${SAMPLE}_1_val_1.fq -2 /home/${SAMPLE}_1_val_2.fq -S ${SAMPLE}.sam | 2>summary.txt

done
```

Comment: What language is this?  Linux script?  R?

Comment: it's just linux bash

Comment: while KamilCuk's answer is likely what you're looking for; a simple fix to the current code: change `| 2>summary.txt` (overwrites `summary.txt` on each pass through loop) to `2>>summary.txt` (appends to `summary.txt` on each pass through loop); the 'extra' pipe (`|`) probably shouldn't be there if all you want to do is capture stderr

Comment: 2>>summary.txt worked perfectly. Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You redirect the *file descriptor* for all *commands* within the loop.

```
for anything in anything; do
    anything
done 2>summary.txt
```